# Необходимо сместить точку привязки контрола на угол квадрата внутри контрола

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, uwp, avalonia

Имеется самодельный контрол такого типа. Необходимо разместить его на канвасе. Мне известны только координаты верхнего левого угла прямоугольника внутри контрола. Как мне разместить контрол, у которого прямоугольник находится под текстом? Размеры текста заранее не известны. Известен только размер прямоугольника и его координаты. Тест расположен относительно прямоугольника.
Вьюмодели контролов хранятся в итемлист. И размещаются на канвасе

```
<ItemsControl.Styles>
    <Style Selector="ItemsControl > ContentPresenter">
        <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding XPosition_Final}"/>
        <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding YPosition_Final}"/>
    </Style>
</ItemsControl.Styles>
```

При этом они могут быть повернуты вокруг этого угла (но это решилось смещением ТрансформОриджин в коде контрола) Не удается только правильно спозиционировать их(
[image: контрол]

Если текст снизу квадрата, то контрол позиционируется правильно (т.к. верхний левый угол квадрата = верхнему левому углу контрола)[image: правильно спозиционировано]
Если текст находится сверху квадрата, то контрол контрол позиционируется по своему верхнему левому углу, а не по углу квадрата. Это не правильное размещение[image: Не правильно разместился]
Требуется разместить контрол вот так.[image: Как требуется разместить]
На руках у меня координаты углов квадрата. Размер текста во вьюмоделе вычислить нет возможности. Пробовал менять трансформ ориджин контрола,не помогло.

Comment: Ничего непонятно. Вам нужно как слева или как справа, и что на скрине не так? При чем здесь канвас? Канвас для рисования предназначен, а не для верстки текстовых блоков. Покажите модель, покажите XAML. Что такое "айтемлист"? Такого класса нет в дотнете. Без канваса оно по идее решается с помощью обычной StackPanel. UWP, WPF или Avalonia у вас? Или вы просто так наспамили тегами?

Comment: У меня Авалония, но я думаю вопрос решается одинаково в любом XAML фреймворке... 
С ItemsList попутал( писал ночью( ItemsControl отвечает за представление колекции.
А итемы коллекции размещаются на канвасе.
На скрине самодельный контрол на основе реверсивной стекпанели. В зависимости от параметров вьюмодели контрол может иметь разный вид. Но мне известны только координаты углов квадрата, который находится внутри контрола, тескст это вещь вспомогательная, вместо него может быть что угодно.

Comment: Стало еще менее понятно. Было бы неплохо, если бы вы показали воспроизводимый пример, хотя-бы на базе WPF. Так зачем канвас то? Какую задачу вы решаете?

Comment: В приложение приходит набор объектов - координаты углов прямоугольника + сообщение. Мне необходимо расположить этот прямоугольник на экране компьютера в заданных координатах + рядом с ним текст. Позиция текста может быть сверху, снизу, с боков. на отдалении от прямоугольника, в зависимости от содержания вьюмодели (на самом деле там маржин для квадрата и настройки стекпанели).
Вот собственно и весь вопрос. Мне нужно разместить квадрат и текст относительно него.

Comment: Координаты известны? Высота известна? Размещайте, я не улавливаю проблему. Берете Grid, высотой с канвас, 3 строки (Binding Y, Auto, *), 2 строку выравнываете по своим координатам, например задав левый марджин и высоту первой строки. Если сверху текст то в верхнюю строку грида текст, если снизу, то в нижнюю. Текстблок уж отравнять внутри ячейки вы сможете, я думаю. Канвас тут, впрочем, и не нужен вовсе.

Comment: Отредактировал вопрос. Может быть понятнее станет

Comment: Да мне и так понятно было, я код с нуля писать не хочу, а что делать - выше рассказал.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Внутри контрола получил позицию прямоугольника и задал отрицательный маржин контролу. Все работает как нужно.

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).